# How to report problem with WPF RichTextBox not rendering double-spaced lines correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I've found what looks to me to be a bug in the WPF Richtextbox class.

```
<UserControl x:Class="RtbControl.WpfRichTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RtbControl"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <RichTextBox x:Name="Rtb" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace WpfAppCore
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Body.rtf");
            var rawRtf = File.ReadAllText(path);

            Rtb.Document.Blocks.Clear();

            var tr = new TextRange(Rtb.Document.ContentStart, Rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rawRtf);
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                stream.Position = 0;
                tr.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
                Rtb.CaretPosition = Rtb.CaretPosition.DocumentStart;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The file "Body.rtf" was created in Word and has two paragraphs that are double-spaced. However, that spacing is lost when the file is loaded.

If I load the file into a winforms richtextbox control, the spacing is preserved and I can even change it using the user32.dll SendMessage approach.

This is something I need in my app and it will force me to abandon the WPF approach if I can't get around it. Is there any way to bring this to MS attention to see if they can either set me straight on what I'm doing wrong or at least explain what is happening under the covers?